# Verilog primitives

Tags: verilog, primitive, hdl

Is there any difference between these two?

1.

```
and(O1,input1,input2);
```

2.

```
always(O1 or input1 or input2)
           and(O1,input1,input2);
```

Does the primitive require an `always` block? 
Or it will be accessed whenever values of output (O1) and inputs (input1,input2) changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do the primitive requires an always block?

No! Just like 'assign' statements they do not need an always section.

In fact if you would have tried you would have gotten a syntax error as you can not instance a module or primitive in an always section.

<sub>Also you there would never be a need to put the output `O1` in the sensitivity list.</sub>